# static content in partial view mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have two views as shown below:

boott.cshtml

```
@model model
<div>
    @if (Model.ViewModel != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_b_table", Model)
    }
    <span class="d2-fldr">Enter folder name: </span>

    <input type="text" name="txtName" class="txtFldrname"/>

    <a class="small d2-createfldr" title="Create folder" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus d2-ico"></span>
    <span class="d2-axn">Create folder</span>
    </a>
)
</div>
```

_boott_table.cshtml

```
@model model

<div class="@BOOTSTRAP.ROW">
    -- some content from model
</div>
```

The view boott.cshtml is directly rendered from the controller's action "boott".
The partial view _boott_table.cshtml content changes always based on the option we select in partial view.

When we click on the options in partial view, we are calling the same action method "boott" and renders the partial boott.cshtml and send the html back. 
However there is some static content in boott.cshtml (spans, input, a tag), they are not part of partial view _boott_table.cshtml and should not get re-rendered when ever we click on the options in _boott_table.cshtml. 
How can we handle this situation ?

can somebody advise?/

Comment: why don't you just simply put the rest of the code in else?

Comment: That is not else part. That content should exists even if model is unavailable

Comment: instead of `we are calling the same action method "boott" and renders the partial boott.cshtml and send the html back.` call a new action which just renders the patirl view _boott_table